# Change the Value of Cell of DataGridView from other Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 forms:

1. `Form1` contains `DataGridView` controls
2. `Form2` contains `Textbox` controls (are in mode read only), checkBox and Button.

When I select a `DataGridView` Row it will show me Form2 and display their values in TextBoxes. Everything seems better just now.
What I want know is after displaying data in textboxes, I check the RadioButton then click the button it will return to Form1 of the selected Row and **Change the value of Cell 4** automatically.

Here there is My code:

Form1

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)  
   {  
       DataGridViewCell cell = null;  
       foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)  
       {  
           cell = selectedCell;  
           break;  
       }  
       if (cell != null)  
       {  
           DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;  
           string objet = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();  
           string objectif = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();  
           string date = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();  
           string commentaire = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();  
           string client = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();  
           string commercial = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();  

           Détails_RDV détails = new Détails_RDV();  

           détails.obj = objet;  
           détails.objectif = objectif;  
           détails.date = date;  
           détails.comm = commentaire;  
           détails.clt = client;  
           détails.commer = commercial;  

           détails.Show();  

       }  
   }
```

Form2

```
public partial class Détails_RDV : Form  
{  
    public string obj ;  
    public string objectif;  
    public string date;  
    public string comm;  
    public string clt ;  
    public string commer;  

    public Détails_RDV()  
    {  
        InitializeComponent();  

    }  

    private void Détails_RDV_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  

        txtObjet.Text = obj;  
        txtObjectif.Text = objectif;  
        txtDate.Text = date;  
        txtCommerci.Text = commer;  
        txtClient.Text = clt;  
        txtCommentaire.Text = comm;  
    }  

    private void btnValider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (checkEffectue.Checked == true)  
        {  
           //What should I write here??
             Liste_RDV lrdv = new Liste_RDV();
             lrdv.Show();

        }  
    }
```

How Can I do That ?

Answer (score 1):

In the button click event on `Form2`, check if the check box is checked, just set `DialogResult` to `OK`, else set it to `Cancel`:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
else
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
```

In `Form1`, instead of `Show`, use `ShowDialog` and check if the result is `OK`, perform the update which you need:

```
var f2 = new Form2();
//Set values
if(f2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Perform update here
}
```

This way each form has its own responsibility and you write the codes which are related to `Form1` in `Form1` and you don't need to write them in `Form2`.

Comment: I don't see the benefit to do that . My Problem is not in **DialogResult**

Comment: It's your decision. This you each form has its own responsibility and you write the codes which are related to `Form1` in `Form1` and you don't need to write them in `Form2`.

Comment: I believe the current post answers your question. But if you need more information about interaction between forms, you may find this post useful: [Interaction between Forms - How to Change a Control of a Form from Another Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768737/interaction-between-forms-how-to-change-a-control-of-a-form-from-another-form)

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event on the sub-form and fire it, as in the example below :

```
public partial class Détails_RDV : Form
{
    public string obj;
    public string objectif;
    public string date;
    public string comm;
    public string clt;
    public string commer;

    **// Event fired on effectue checkbox change
    public class EffectueEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public EffectueEventArgs(bool val)
        {
            Effectue = val;
        }
        public bool Effectue { get; private set; }
    }
    public delegate void EffectueChangeHandler(object src, EffectueEventArgs e);
    public event EffectueChangeHandler OnEffectueChange;**

    public Détails_RDV()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Détails_RDV_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtObjet.Text = obj;
        txtObjectif.Text = objectif;
        txtDate.Text = date;
        txtCommerci.Text = commer;
        txtClient.Text = clt;
        txtCommentaire.Text = comm;
    }

    private void btnValider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkEffectue.Checked == true)
        {
            **// Notify any event listener of change
            if (OnEffectueChange != null)
                OnEffectueChange (this, new EffectueEventArgs(true);**

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you create the sub-form youc an subscribe to the event and register an appropriate handler, e.g.

```
        Détails_RDV détails = new Détails_RDV();
        détails.obj = objet;
        détails.objectif = objectif;
        détails.date = date;
        détails.comm = commentaire;
        détails.clt = client;
        détails.commer = commercial;
        **détails.OnEffectueChange += (src, e) => { row.Cells[4].Value = e.Effectue; };**
        détails.Show();
```

Or you could leverage INotifyPropertyChanged, or indeed specify an explicit callback delegate, Action or Function.